# What does $define() do in java android studio source code do and how can I view and change this

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am looking at some java code in Android Studio which compiles to an apk for Android. In this code there is initialization code inside $define(){....}. What does this do and how can I see this and modify it. The code comments says it is similar to main in Java.

Following is code:

```
package com.example.bparent.redbutton3;

import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.Form;

//package com.example.paintpot;

import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.HandlesEventDispatching;
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.Form;
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.EventDispatcher;
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.Component;

import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.HorizontalArrangement;
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.Button;
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.Camera;
import com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.Canvas;

public class Screen1 extends Form implements HandlesEventDispatching
{

    private float dotSize;

    private Canvas canvas1;
    private HorizontalArrangement horizontalArrangement1;
    private Button redButton;
    private Button blueButton;
    private Button greenButton;
    private Button bigButton;
    private Button smallButton;
    private Button takePictureButton;
    private Camera camera1;

    protected void $define()
    {
        this.Title("Paint Pot");
        this.Icon("kitty.png");
        dotSize = 2;
        canvas1 = new Canvas( this );
        canvas1.Height( 300 );
        canvas1.Width(LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
        canvas1.BackgroundImage( "kitty.png" );

        canvas1.PaintColor(COLOR_RED);

        horizontalArrangement1 = new HorizontalArrangement( this );
        horizontalArrangement1.Width(LENGTH_FILL_PARENT);
```

Comment: What is your question? You're speaking about some code but we don't see your screen.

Comment: I have added some code showing use of $define in code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$define` is a valid identifier in Java, nothing special about it. So the code defines a protected method called `$define`.